# An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header (c#) + WS-Security Timestamp

Tags: c#, header, ws-security

I am getting an error which says :

> "An error was discovered processing the  header"

While I am trying to communicate to web service.

How can I add `"WS-Security Timestamp"` to the soap request ?